# Split empty string should return empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I use

```
''.split(',')
```

I get `['']` instead of an empty array `[]`.

How do I make sure that an empty string always returns me an empty array?

Comment: Write your own `split` replacement and break compatibility? If you split a non-empty string on `','` you get back an array with the original string in it, just like here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do a simple check if the string is falsy before calling split:

```
function returnArr(str){
  return !str ? [] : str.split(',')
}

returnArr('1,2,3')
// ['1','2','3']
returnArr('')
//[]
```

Comment: But I still want `'p,q,r'.split(',').splice()` to split into an array of 3 elements

Comment: Would break if you actually had a non-empty string, though; this seems like a special case that would be more easily handled by just checking for an empty string.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.  As @mortensen asked in this comment that `'p,q,r'.split(',').splice()` will return an empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

try with   this

```
  r=s?s.split(','):[];
```

Comment: I think you'd want the last `s` to be an empty array.

Comment: Then how did you have time to answer it?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = ''.split(',').filter(Boolean);
console.log('result:', arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do it;

```js
console.log(''.split(',').reduce((p,c) => c ? p.concat(c) : p ,[]));
console.log("test1,test2,".split(',').reduce((p,c) => c ? p.concat(c) : p ,[]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator

```js
let text1 = ''
let text2 = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'

console.log(text1 == '' ? [] : text1.split(','));
console.log(text2 == '' ? [] : text2.split(','));
```

Answer (score -2):

split() always splits into pieces (at least one) so you can try:

```
list=(!l)?[]:l.split(',');
```

Also you can write a new split method like:

```
String.prototype.split2 = function (ch) { 
   return (!this)?[]:this.split(ch) 
}
```

So tou can try:

```
''.split2(',');         //result: []
'p,q,r'.split2(',');    //result: ['p','q','r']
```