# Why is this array.length return 1 for an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using:

```
<input id="selectedRecords" name="selectedRecords" type="hidden" />
```

Executing this code:

```
var keyValues = $('#selectedRecords').val().split(",").map(item => item.trim());

console.log('$(#selectedRecords).val(): [' + $('#selectedRecords').val() + ']');
console.log('keyValues: [' + keyValues + ']');
console.log('keyValues.length: [' + keyValues.length + ']');
```

Gives this console readout (copy pasted from console window in Brave browser):

```
$(#selectedRecords).val(): []
keyValues: []
keyValues.length: [1]
```

Why is keyValues.length returning a count of 1 ?

```js
var keyValues = $('#selectedRecords').val().split(",").map(item => item.trim());

console.log('$(#selectedRecords).val(): [' + $('#selectedRecords').val() + ']');
console.log('keyValues: [' + keyValues + ']');
console.log('keyValues.length: [' + keyValues.length + ']');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selectedRecords" name="selectedRecords" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: `keyValues` contains an array with one element, the empty string `''`.

Comment: Your debugging approach is flawed and based on false assumptions.  Instead of concatenating `keyValues` into strings in a variety of ways, log `keyValues` *itself* to the console and observe what it actually is.

Comment: `.split(',')` can't return an empty array. The only way for `String.prototype.split` to return an empty array is `''.split('')`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: It's closed because *it's not useful for future visitors*. It may be reproducible but so what? The question is "if I don't debug properly, why do I reach wrong conclusions" which is hardly something for the ages. Even if we don't go with the current close reason, this is a duplicate. The main dupe target would be [Javascript console.log(object) vs. concatenating string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14597246) then maybe a few others can be added.

Comment: @PaulZahra I was under the impression you did not understand the closure, so I explained the rationale. In the future, I shall endeavour to not do that, since you appear to consider the explanation "unkind".

Comment: @VLAZ sorry, the reason given for closure was "not reproducible or was caused by typos",  so the very fact that it is reproducible is relevant, and it isn't a typo (A typographical error). P.S. I was under the impression that posters should be curt and respectful of others, as opposed to uncharitable and bordering on belligerence, my bad. To the point, how is it possible to edit this post to pass for reopening? i.e. the reasons for closure don't seem to apply. Given that I cannot delete it because it was answered.

Comment: First, you should fix the question. The current question is based on a wrong assumption and doesn't make sense. An empty array doesn't have length 1. Debug and isolate the problem and ask a specific question, something like _"Why is the string representation of `[""]` an empty string"_. Then, the question can probably be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @jabaa Perhaps, now I have made the question make sense, but now some comments and indeed the marked answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: Now the question is a duplicate of: [The confusion about the split() function of JavaScript with an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5164883) Also related: [Split empty string should return empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39755867)

Comment: @VLAZ Yes... given that when I asked the initial question I wasn't aware that the issue was arising from split (and of my concatenating an object) rather that it made no sense to me that the array had a length of 1, naturally when I understand that the issue does in fact arise from split, and ask accordingly, it will be a duplicate, which I wouldn't have asked in the first place had I known. However I am now intrigued as to why split is designed this way. But hey, mark me down harder for asking a question about something I didn't understand.

Comment: Please don't answer your question in the question. A user has posted a correct answer. You are allowed to answer your own question, but you would create and post an answer. Please don't change your question after it was answered in a way that invalidates given answers. If you have a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: You should always follow [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before you ask a question. Stepping line by line with your debugger through the code would show you that the array wasn't empty.

Comment: Yes indeed, however given that the question was answered within 9 mins of me posting it and closed within 15mins of me posting it "Post Closed as "Not suitable for this site" and I am receiving down votes for a question that I can see is essentially a poorly asked duplicate, and I cannot delete it in accordance with the "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" post.... go figure.

Comment: I think you have two options. Either delete the question or accept the situation. I don't know any third option. Changes to the question that invalidate the answer should always be rolled back. If you're lucky, the question will be deleted by the community.

Comment: @jabaa yes, quite a ridiculous situation, bit paradoxical, it's a stupid question but don't delete because it's been answered... do not delete and hope that it doesn't get more and more downvotes or delete and risk the account being blocked... "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. See "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" for alternatives to deletion.

Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?"

Comment: Your account won't be blocked for deleting one single question. Just don't do it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating things while logging them:

```js
console.log('$(#selectedRecords).val(): [' + $('#selectedRecords').val() + ']');
console.log('keyValues: [' + keyValues + ']');
console.log('keyValues.length: [' + keyValues.length + ']');
```

`keyValues` is `[""]`, but if you concatenate it with a string, its string representation will be used - the comma separated list of its values, in this case just `""`.

Solution: log things right!

```js
console.log('$(#selectedRecords).val()', $('#selectedRecords').val());
console.log('keyValues', keyValues);
console.log('keyValues.length', keyValues.length);
```